# when I try to send a message to a discord channel it repeats the message

Tags: discord.py

when my discord bot tries to send a message to a discord server it repeats the message.

main program code:

```
if message.content == "-play":
    player = message.author
    player_created = "True"
    if player in players:
        pass
    else:
        players.append(player)
        inventories.update({player.name: []})
        positions.update({player.name: "start location"})
# message not -play
else:
    # if a player exists
    if player_created == "True":
        if positions[player.name] == "start location":
            text = main3_functions.example_room(inventories)
        await message.channel.send(text)
```

Comment: Do not post pictures within your question, you're supposed to add it in a codeblock in the question itself. Please edit your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a lot of information. Please look at ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question. Add every information you have that might help us, but keep it as short as possible. If you have a question about code, please include the code. You can also take this short [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about Stack Overflow. Also provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so strangers can test your code and reproduce your errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

This should be added at the top of the code so it would ignore messages from the bot itself.

Answer (score 0):

It repeats, because the bot takes it's own message as 'command'. So it checks if the message content is right, but it cannot be right. So what you have to do, is add to the else statement

`if message.user.id != bot.user.id:`